# Split Image in regions with min area threshold

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am using Watershed to split my image in regions. The regions generated are good, but there are some very small regions that I want to remove.

Is there a way to add a 'min area threshold' to watershed or do a post processing to merge very small regions?

Here is one example of image:
[image: blobs]

Here is the result and the problem (very small region marked in red)
[image]

Code to run example:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure, segmentation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.zeros((50,50))
# top left
image[8:28, 3:21] = 1
# top right
image[3:12, 30:47] =  image[17:20, 30:35] =  image[15:18, 39:44] = 1
# bottom left 
image[46:48, 3:5] =  image[46:48, 13:18] =  image[42:45, 2:7] =  image[35,25] = 1
# bottom right
image[38:45, 33:38] =  image[35:38, 38:45] =  image[43:48, 40:45] = image[39,40] = 1


labeled_regions= measure.label(image, connectivity=2)

label_ws = segmentation.watershed(np.ones_like(image), markers=labeled_regions)

fig = plt.imshow(image)
plt.savefig('blobs.png')
plt.imshow(label_ws)
plt.savefig('regions.png')
```

Comment: why don't you modify the `image` before you use the `measure.label` function ?

Comment: You'll have to make a choice -- what other region should the pixels in the small region be assigned to?

Comment: It could be any adjacent region, doesn't really matter.

Comment: @seralouk This could work, but one problem is that I don't know exactly where the small regions will be after the 'zoning'. I tried to use dilation, but it ends up merging big squares that are near and it ends up creating a really big region at the end.